# ActiveMQ Classic SSL - Reload truststore with out restart broker

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, activemq-classic, truststore

I'm using ActiveMQ Classic as my messages server.

In order to keep it secure between the server and the clients (producer/consumer), I added to the `activemq.xml` an SSL context section with a keystore and truststore file to use.

In case the truststore has be updated with a new certifiate, I would like ActiveMQ Classic to reload the truststore without restarting the broker itself.

Is there any way to do it?

I found [something similar](http://activemq.apache.org/runtime-configuration.html), but I don't know this is what I need.

Comment: Im using Spring to configure SSL for a Broker instance ( java)

Comment: Take a look at ActiveMQ Artemis (i.e. the next-generation of ActiveMQ). It will automatically reload SSL certs when they are changed on disk. All existing connections will be undisturbed and all new connections will use the new cert(s). Eventually all the old connections will disconnect naturally or they can be selectively closed administratively if necessary. This avoid the need to restart the entire broker.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to update the certificate without dropping all the client connections, which is effectively restarting it anyway.

Using the runtime-configuration wouldn't help with this configuration change in that you'd still have to drop client connections.

Having a failover broker (aka slave broker) or a network-of-brokers would help you in this case. You could upgrade the "other broker", then have clients failover to the updated one, then upgrade the original broker.